# compose several values ​into one value in R

Tags: r, regression

I have a dataset for survived people on Titanic. Then I have tried to check if there is a correlation between survivors and the number of siblings on board. But there are too low data number on siblings over 2 so I will in my test in stead make two variable 0 for no siblings and 1 for at least 1 sibling. But how can I do this in R?

[image]
[image]

Comment: A plot like I have added now or what do you mean?

Comment: Nothing.  thanks, good luck

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(titanic)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(titanic, 20))`.

Comment: If the variable is named `x`, try `as.integer(x > 0)` or, marginally faster, `+(x > 0)`.

Comment: Nice that works. Thank you. But when I rin the then it just change it, but when I dataframe my data again its just the old data. How can I incorporate this edit in the data?

Comment: Rui Barradas can you help me?

Comment: You need to assign the value back to data. `titanic$binary <- as.integer(titanic$siblings > 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of any `dput`data let me use some toy data to illustrate the solution:

```
titanic <- data.frame(
  randomVar = c(LETTERS[1:10]),
  siblings = c(1,0,2,3,5,1,0,2,0,1)
)
```

If you want to replace the count data in the column `siblings`with binary values, i.e., `0` and `1`, you can do this using an `ifelse` statement:

```
titanic$sibl_binary <- ifelse(titanic$siblings == 0, # condition to meet
                          0,                         # what to do if the condition is met
                          1)                         # what to do if the condition is not met
```

The result:

```
titanic
   randomVar siblings sibl_binary
1          A        1           1
2          B        0           0
3          C        2           1
4          D        3           1
5          E        5           1
6          F        1           1
7          G        0           0
8          H        2           1
9          I        0           0
10         J        1           1
```